# Center a div box using css and html without centering the text in the box

Tags: css, forms, html

I want to center the div box im making here but i dont want to center the text in the box and i cant seem to find how to do this. For now what i have is this:

```
.box {
        text-align: left;
        background-color:#3F48CC;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin:120px auto;
        height:150px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
    }
```

and

```
<div class=box>
    Login
    <form method ="post" action="addMember.php">
      <label for="name">Username:</label>
      <input name="name"/>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input name="password"/>
        <p>
        <input name="submit" type="Submit" value="Register"/>
        <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Clear Form">
  </form>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `display: inline-block;` & `text-align:center`

`inline-block` is not necessary when you are defining the `width/height` for the div.

By default div is a `block` element.

```
.box {       
        background-color:#3F48CC;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin:120px auto;
        height:150px;        
        width: 200px;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UbXs4/1/)**

Comment: This is not exactly centered vertically!

Comment: @PraveenKumar He is not asking for vertical middle alignment.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use dead centre...

```
.box {
    text-align: left;
    background-color:#3F48CC;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:150px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```

**Note:** Negative margins are exactly half the height and width, which pull the element back into perfect center. Only works with elements of a fixed height/width.

#### More info:

- [CSS Tricks Example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/)
- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DPBRe/)

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3HUbf/1/)

[**Alternate jsFiddle DEMO with Centered Form**](http://jsfiddle.net/NEtFZ/2/) and also this [**CSS3 Version**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr5UT/2/).

The key to making the form look correct is to use `padding`, which is part of box model. Doing so allows you to fill in the sides, and keeps the text left-hand aligned.

**HTML**

```html
<div class=box>Login
  <form method="post" action="addMember.php">
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input name="name" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input name="password" />
    <div class="buttons">
      <input name="submit" type="Submit" value="Register" />
      <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Clear Form" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.box {
  background-color:#3F48CC;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  height:150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttons{
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]